# generic with new() constraint, can't take string as type

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have written a generic class

```
 class MyClass : MyClass<string> { } //this line is in error

 class MyClass<OutputBaseType> : MyClass<OutputBaseType, List<OutputBaseType>>
     where OutputBaseType : new() //this new constraint is needed
 {}
 class MyClass<OutputBaseType,OutputType> 
    where OutputType : ICollection<OutputBaseType>, new()
    where OutputBaseType : new()
 {
     public void Method(OutputBaseType z)
     {
         if (z!=null) { ... }
     }
 ...
 }
```

Because string has no default constructor the first line will now work. If I remove this line and modify clients to explicitly define string, then it does not work for the same reason.

If I remove  `where OutputBaseType : new()`  and the other `new()` then it works with `OutputBaseType` of `string` but not with `OutputType` of `dictionary<...>`. This is because `KeyValuePair<>` used by dictionary is a `struct` not a `class`, so can not be `null`. (I don't like null usually but need it here)

Is there a way to get this to work?

---

Amendments:

I have removed new constraint on OutputBaseType.
Then replaced assigning of null and assigning with default construction, with default(OutputBaseType)

This looks promising but I now have an error in the condition expression on line

```
OutputBaseType outputItem = ...;
if (outputItem != default(OutputBaseType)) { _Output.Add(outputItem); }
```

The error is:

```
Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'OutputBaseType' and 'OutputBaseType'
```

Comment: It's hard to say what counts as "get this to work" when we don't know what you're trying to achieve. You've given a somewhat confusing account of what *doesn't* work, but that's not the same thing. Maybe if you could *clearly* explain what you want to achieve, we may have an alternative design.

Comment: In a non-generic version, you wouldn't be able to compare a `KeyValuePair` against null either. What is it you're trying to accomplish with that null check?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If I remove where OutputBaseType : new() and the other new() then it works with string OutputBaseType but not with dictionary as OutputType. This is because KeyValuePair<> used by dictionary is a struct not a class, so can not be null. (I don't like null usually but need it here)

You can simply use `default(T)` instead of `null` for value types. The default constructor of value types cannot be user defined, and always initializes all fields to their default value (`0`, `null`,...). So you don't need the `new()` constraint if you just use `default(T)` instead of `new T()`, since for value types they are equivalent, and for reference types you want `null` which happens to be the `default` of any reference type.

---

`==` is not available on generic types. You can either use `object.Equals` (this causes boxing) or `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals`. I prefer the second one:

```
EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(outputItem, default(OutputBaseType))
```

Comment: Well, what about Int32? You cannot tell the difference between uninitialized (default zero), or an actual zero...

Comment: You cannot tell the difference between `0` and `new Int32()` either, because those are the same. You'd need to use `int?` to get such a value. Having a `new()` constraint doesn't magically allow a value type to become `null`.

Comment: Yes this did about 90% but I still have a compile error (See Question). Thanks so far.

Comment: @richard added a bit on comparing generic types.

Comment: That comparer is ugly but it works. All the old tests are still green and a new test to check result type (when using dictionary) is now green. I think I will get the other test to pass when I finish writing the code.

Answer (score 1):

The `: new()` constraint means "the type must have a parameterless constructor", and allows you to use `new T()` inside your generic class. [`System.String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) doesn't have a parameterless constructor, so you can't do `new String()`, which means it doesn't satisfy the `: new()` type constraint.

Perhaps you wanted `: class` instead? That doesn't say anything about constructors, it just says it has to be a reference type. That will allow you to use `!= null` in your class, and it will allow you to use `String` as the type argument.

Comment: Then he still can't use `KeyValuePair<,>`

Comment: because sometimes I have a reference type and some times a value type. I sometimes need to set/compare with null and sometimes with whatever nothingness the default constructor produces (assuming I am not using integers or other value types where everything is equally valid). It looks like default and EqualityComparer were created for this (see accepted answer).

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was

```
abstract class ABase<T> 
{
  public T field;
}

abstract class ATypedBase<T> : ABase<T> where T : new() 
{
  public new T field = new T();
}

class Test1 : ABase<string> {}
class Test2 : ATypedBase<Item> {}
```